# Creating a chat bot in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, chatbot

I have a question about tkinter and chatbots in python.

First off I'd just like to tell everyone my aims for this chatbot:

- Must be a GUI
- Must be able to type an input into the messageWindow
- If the input that was typed into messageWindow contains a certain keyword then a response will be printed into the chatWindow by the "bot" which the user can then see and perhaps click links.

I have the first design for the GUI created but I'm unsure how to actually make this chatbot work.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import * #library

root = Tk() #creates the tkinter object
root.title("Helper") #title for the window
root.geometry("400x450") #sets windows dimensions

main_menu = Menu(root) #creates main menu bar for text to appear

file_menu = Menu(root) #creates submenu
file_menu.add_command(label="New..") #command for submenu "File"
file_menu.add_command(label="Save As..") #command for submenu "File"
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit") #command for submenu "File"

main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu = file_menu)
main_menu.add_command(label="Edit")
main_menu.add_command(label="Quit")
root.config(menu=main_menu)

chatWindow = Text(root, bd=1, bg="white", width = 50, height = 8)
chatWindow.place(x = 6, y = 6, height = 270, width = 370)

messageWindow = Text(root, bg="white", width = 30, height = 4)
messageWindow.place(x = 6, y = 280, height = 88, width = 260)

Button = Button(root, text="Send", bg="blue", fg="white", activebackground="light blue", width = 12, height = 5, font=("Arial", 18, "bold"))
Button.place(x=275, y=280, height=88, width=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi. Just to clarify your question. Regardless of the ChatBOT AI code, you are asking how to interactively handle text input?

Comment: Have you written any code for the chatbot yourself? If yes then it'll be helpful to see what you have tried as of now, and if not, to clarify SO questions must be written incase any help is needed with already tried code, since the way a chatbot can be made is widely described all throughout the internet.

Comment: "any help" is not a suitable question for Stackoverflow. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

To type input into the message window, use `Entry` instead of `Text` so that you can get the input from the entry field and do what you want with it.

You can pass `command=[function no parenthesis]` to the send button to run a function every time the button is pressed. In this case function to get what is in the entryfield if a certain word has been entered.

The `chatWindow` is better as a `Frame` to put labels(text) within. As you've said you want the chat window to display something when input contains a certain keyword you can write a function for that like:

```
def entered():
    if "test" in messageWindow.get(): #.get() retrieves the text in the Entry field
        Label(chatWindow,text="Hi",bg="white").pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW) #Place text label within Frame if the keyword in this case "test" is in the Entry field
        link_label = Label(chatWindow,text="This is a link",bg="white",font=('Arial', 10,'underline'))
        link_label.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
        link_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: webbrowser.open_new("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864931/creating-a-chat-bot-in-python"))
```

To break down the above, `if "test" in messageWindow.get():` the .get() retrieves text within the Entryfield and would check if it contains "test". For your case use what you'd like. Then the text will be displayed with `Label(chatWindow,text="Hi",bg="white").pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)`(the side and anchor arguments is to keep the text to the left).

For links you need to `import webbrowser` which will allow you to use links, create your label `link_label = Label(chatWindow,text="This is a link",bg="white",font=('Arial', 10,'underline'))` then pack it separately `link_label.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)` so that you can bind a link to it. In this case the link is the link to this question.

Changed code altogether:

```
chatWindow = Frame(root, bd=1, bg="white", width = 50, height = 8)
chatWindow.place(x = 6, y = 6, height = 270, width = 370)

messageWindow = Entry(root, bg="white", width = 30)
messageWindow.place(x = 6, y = 280, height = 88, width = 260)

def entered():
    if "test" in messageWindow.get():
        Label(chatWindow,text="Hi",bg="white").pack(side=TOP, anchor=NW)
        link_label = Label(chatWindow,text="This is a link",bg="white",font=('Arial', 10,'underline'))
        link_label.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
        link_label.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: webbrowser.open_new("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70864931/creating-a-chat-bot-in-python"))

Button = Button(root, text="Send", bg="blue", fg="white", activebackground="light blue", width = 12, height = 5, font=("Arial", 18, "bold"),command=entered)
Button.place(x=275, y=280, height=88, width=100)
```